# jQuery Ajax post breaks when I don't reset Ajax response area with .html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the following code to post a form via Ajax, everything is working fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".button2").submit(function() { return false; });
$(".button3").submit(function() { return false; });
$(".button4").submit(function() { return false; });

$(document).on("click",'.button1, .button2, .button3, .button4', function() {

    var formData = $(this).closest('.bookroom1, .bookroom2, .bookroom3, .bookroom4').serializeArray();
    formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: AJAX_URL,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            if (response.status == 'success') {
                $('.bookroom1, .bookroom2, .bookroom3, .bookroom4')[0].reset();
            }

            $('.booking-main').html(response.content);
            $('.booking-side-response').html(response.sidebar);

            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

        }
    });

    $('.booking-main').html('<img src="http://website.com/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">');
    $('.booking-side-response').html('<img src="http://website.com/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">');

});

});
```

When the Ajax is submit this code deletes the existing content in the response areas and replaces it with a loading gif until the response comes:

```
$('.booking-main').html('<img src="http://website.com/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">');
$('.booking-side-response').html('<img src="http://website.com/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">');
```

If I remove these two lines so no loading gif displays the Ajax breaks (fails to load according to the JS error console) and the form is submit using a GET and all the data appears in the browser URL bar.

Does anyone know what is causing this to happen?

I just want the old div content to be replaced by the new Ajax response content with no loading.gif in between.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a jsfiddle? I'm not seeing anything that would cause that problem.

Comment: Don't see any problem with your JS code. Could you please share your HTML code too?

Comment: Are the buttons within a ".booking-main"?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @rism yes the buttons are inside the ".booking-main" div, would this cause any issues?

Comment: @Christopher Meyers, the code is part of a much larger project but I'll try and get a separate working jsfiddle online soon

Comment: Well, potentially, not in a position to test it out but if you look at the api page for `.html` https://api.jquery.com/html/ it says replace content and ` Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.` so I'm thinking it's your event handlers firing when they shouldn't because now you're not doing a replace and therefore not removing the handlers. Try replacing your html calls  with a `return false;` because now your buttons are still in there and you have active click /submit events.

Comment: Ah that's it!! I replaced them with return: false and it's working fine now. Thanks!